# Enquiry: Beautiful soup + a href pattern not scraping like I want

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I have the following html pattern I want to scrap using BeautifulSoup. The html pattern is:

```
<a href="link" target="_blank" onclick="blah blah blah">TITLE</a>
```

I want to grab TITLE and the information that is displayed in the link. That is, if you clicked the link there is a a description of the TITLE. I want that description.

I started with just trying to grab the title with the following code:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

webpage = urrlib.urlopen("http://urlofinterest")

title = re.compile('<a>(.*)</a>')
findTitle = re.findall(title,webpage)
print findTile
```

My output is:

```
% python beta2.py
[]
```

So this is obviously not even finding the title. I even tried `<a href>(.*)</a>` and that didn't work. Based on my reading of the documentation and I thought BeautifulSoup will grab whatever text is between the symbols I give it. In this case, , so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: surely it should be print findTitle instead of findTile?

Comment: The re pattern you compile does not match the link, try this re.compile('<a .*>(.*?)<\/a>') ...practice here https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How come you're importing beautifulsoup and then not using it at all?

```
webpage = urrlib.urlopen("http://urlofinterest")
```

You'll want to read the data from this, so that:

```
webpage = urrlib.urlopen("http://urlofinterest").read()
```

Something like (should get you to a point to go further):

```
>>> blah = '<a href="link" target="_blank" onclick="blah blah blah">TITLE</a>'
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(blah) # change to webpage later
>>> for tag in soup('a', href=True):
    print tag['href'], tag.string

link TITLE
```

Comment: I got it to work. I also got it to sort the exact URLS I wanted!I use if 'i_need_this' in tag['href'] and that only printed the URLS I wanted. So my next question is how do I grab the info in that link though? There is a description of the title in the link I want, and maybe a few other things.